# scala.concurrent.blocking - what does it actually do?

Tags: scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have spent a while learning the topic of Scala execution contexts, underlying threading models and concurrency. Can you explain in what ways does `scala.concurrent.blocking` *"adjust the runtime behavior"* and *"may improve performance or avoid deadlocks"* as described in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.concurrent.package)?

In [the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html), it is presented as a means to await api that doesn't implement Awaitable. (Perhaps also just long running computation should be wrapped?).

What is it that it actually does?

[Following through the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L54) doesn't easily betray its secrets.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`blocking` is meant to act as a hint to the `ExecutionContext` that the contained code is blocking and could lead to thread starvation. This will give the thread pool a chance to spawn new threads in order to prevent starvation. This is what is meant by *"adjust the runtime behavior"*. It's not magic though, and won't work with every `ExecutionContext`.

Consider this example:

```
import scala.concurrent._
val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

(0 to 100) foreach { n =>
    Future {
        println("starting Future: " + n)
        blocking { Thread.sleep(3000) }
        println("ending Future: " + n)
    }(ec)
}
```

This is using the default global `ExecutionContext`. Running the code as-is, you will notice that the 100 `Future`s are all executed immediately, but if you remove `blocking`, they only execute a few at a time. The default `ExecutionContext` will react to blocking calls (marked as such) by spawning new threads, and thus doesn't get overloaded with running `Future`s.

Now look at this example with a fixed pool of 4 threads:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)

(0 to 100) foreach { n =>
    Future {
        println("starting Future: " + n)
        blocking { Thread.sleep(3000) }
        println("ending Future: " + n)
    }(ec)
}
```

This `ExecutionContext` isn't built to handle spawning new threads, and so even with my blocking code surrounded with `blocking`, you can see that it will still only execute at most 4 `Future`s at a time. And so that's why we say it *"may improve performance or avoid deadlocks"*--it's not guaranteed. As we see in the latter `ExecutionContext`, it's not guaranteed at all.

How does it work? As linked, `blocking` executes this code:

```
BlockContext.current.blockOn(body)(scala.concurrent.AwaitPermission)
```

`BlockContext.current` retrieves the `BlockContext` from the current thread, seen [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/BlockContext.scala#L59-65). A `BlockContext` is usually just a `Thread` with the `BlockContext` trait mixed in. As seen in the source, it is either stored in a `ThreadLocal`, or if it's not found there, it is pattern matched out of the current thread. If the current thread is not a `BlockContext`, then the `DefaultBlockContext` is used instead.

Next, `blockOn` is called on the current `BlockContext`. `blockOn` is an abstract method in `BlockContext`, so it's implementation is dependent on how the `ExecutionContext` handles it. If we look at the [implementation for `DefaultBlockContext`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/BlockContext.scala#L52-54) (when the current thread is not a `BlockContext`), we see that `blockOn` actually does nothing there. So using `blocking` in a non-`BlockContext` means that nothing special is done at all, and the code is run as-is, with no side-effects.

What about threads that are `BlockContext`s? For instance, in the `global` context, seen [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L40-56), `blockOn` does quite a bit more. Digging deeper, you can see that it's using a `ForkJoinPool` under the hood, with the `DefaultThreadFactory` defined in the same snippet being used for spawning new threads in the `ForkJoinPool`. Without the implementation of `blockOn` from the `BlockContext` (thread), the `ForkJoinPool` doesn't know you're blocking, and won't try to spawn more threads in response.

Scala's [`Await`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/fdb3d96409033ea0b15a37118c423618ac00acb5/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L148) too, uses `blocking` for its implementation.

Comment: It seems this is purely delegating the magic to Java's [`util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool's`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html) discretion, aside some deprecated scala code. I wonder then, how does Java's fork join implementation then decide whether/when to spawn a new thread. Java's thread statuses may seem a little [insufficient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED) as a criteria, unless _any blocking code_ would involve a monitor lock.

Comment: As for how ForkJoinPool decides, you might find the answer in the [source](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java.html) a little less than satisfying. Things start to get very low level.  `addWorker` can create new threads from the `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`, which is called in two places: `signalWork` and `tryPreBlock`. Both of which contain some exciting amounts of bitwise logic.

Comment: Let us leave that for a separate question (or book)... 

until shown otherwise, I shall assume most blocking api may be well enough detectable by that Java 7 implementation, except for a long cpu intensive task that may also be considered "blocking" in a TypeSafe "Reactive Applications" view.