# blocking keyword in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, io, future

What's the difference between `Future(blocking(blockingCall()))` and `blocking(Future(blockingCall()))`? Both of these are defined in `scala.concurrent._`

I've looked [at the scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking) and some other [stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097754/asynchronous-io-in-scala-with-futures#answer-13099594) but remain unclear on what the difference is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`blocking` acts as a hint to the `ExecutionContext` that it contains blocking code, so that it may spawn a new thread to prevent deadlocks. This presumes the `ExecutionContext` can do that, but not all are made to.

Let's look at each one-by-one.

---

```
Future(blocking(blockingCall()))
```

This requires an implicit `ExecutionContext` to execute the `Future`. If the `ExecutionContext` being used is a `BlockContext` (like `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is), it may be able to spawn a new thread in its thread pool to handle the blocking call, if it needs to. If it isn't, then nothing special happens.

---

```
blocking(Future(blockingCall()))
```

This tells us that `Future(blockingCall())` may be a blocking call, so it is treated the same as above. Except here, `Future.apply` is non-blocking, so using `blocking` effectively does nothing but add a little overhead. It doesn't matter what `ExecutionContext` we're calling it from here, as it isn't blocking anyway. **However**, the blocking call *within* the `Future` will block a thread in the `ExecutionContext` it's running on, *without* the hint that its blocking. So, there is no reason to ever do this.

I've explained `blocking` more in depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068064/scala-concurrent-blocking-what-does-it-actually-do/29069021#29069021).

---

REPL Examples:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._
val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val ec2 = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)

def blockingCall(i: Int): Unit = { Thread.sleep(1000); println("blocking call.. " + i) }

// Spawns enough new threads in `ec` to handle the 100 blocking calls
(0 to 100) foreach { i => Future(blocking(blockingCall(i)))(ec) }

// Does not spawn new threads, and `ec2` reaches thread starvation
// execution will be staggered as threads are freed
(0 to 100) foreach { i => Future(blocking(blockingCall(i)))(ec2) }

// `blocking` does nothing because the `Future` is executed in a different context,
// and `ec2` reaches thread starvation
(0 to 100) foreach { i => blocking(Future(blockingCall(i))(ec2)) }

// `blocking` still does nothing, but `ec` does not know to spawn new threads (even though it could)
// so we reach thread starvation again
(0 to 100) foreach { i => blocking(Future(blockingCall(i))(ec)) }
```

Comment: It's also not a keyword, it's just a method.

Comment: That was a great explanation! Thank you so much!