# Does Akka's fork-join-executor make use of scala.concurrent.blocking?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I know that scala.concurrent.blocking is a hint for ExecutionContext that a piece of code performs some long operation / blocks on some IO. ExecutionContext can, but does not have to, make use of this "hint".

As described here:

[scala.concurrent.blocking - what does it actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068064/scala-concurrent-blocking-what-does-it-actually-do/29069021#29069021)

http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-the-blocking-construct-in-scala-futures

scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global is a ForkJoinPool, which spawns a new thread for a code wrapped in scala.concurrent.blocking.

What about Akka's fork-join-executor. Does it also make use of scala.concurrent.blocking in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does!

It's easy enough to figure this out by searching for `BlockContext`. For Akka, that leads us [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/4acc1cca6a27be0ff80f801de3640f91343dce94/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/ThreadPoolBuilder.scala#L158-L176), and if you follow the threads in the code and documentation, you can confirm it.

This is also easy enough to test on our own. We can make a new `ActorSystem` without any configured dispatchers (so it will use the default fork-join-executor), then use its dispatcher as our `ExecutionContext`.

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent._

implicit val ec = ActorSystem("test").dispatcher
```

First, without blocking you will notice that several futures start right away, but not all of them. The another batch will start as the first batch completes. Clearly, the default pool reaches starvation:

```
(0 to 100) foreach { n =>
    Future {
        println("starting Future: " + n)
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        println("ending Future: " + n)
    }
}
```

Then, with `blocking` all of the futures should execute almost immediately, as opposed to the previous example:

```
(0 to 100) foreach { n =>
    Future {
        println("starting Future: " + n)
        blocking(Thread.sleep(3000))
        println("ending Future: " + n)
    }
}
```