# Scala : Futures with map, flatMap for IO/CPU bound tasks

Tags: scala, future

I am aware that in Java 8 it is not a good idea to start long-running tasks in stream framework's filter, map, etc. methods, as there is no way to tune the underlying fork-join pool and it can cause latency problems and starvings.

Now, my question would be, is there any problem like that with Scala? I tried to google it, but I guess I just can't put this question in a google-able sentence.

Let's say I have a list of objects and I want to save them into a database using a forEach, would that cause any issues? I guess this would not be an issue in Scala, as functional transformations are fundamental building blocks of the language, but anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you don't see any kind of I/O operations then using futures can be an overhead.

  `def add(x: Int, y: Int) = Future { x + y }`
- Executing purely CPU-bound operations in a Future constructor will make your logic slower to execute, not faster. Mapping and flatmapping over them, can increase add fuel to this problem.
- In case you want to initialize a `Future` with a constant/simple calculation, you can use `Future.successful()`.
- But all blocking I/O, including SQL queries makes sence be wrapped inside a `Future` with `blocking`

  E.g :

  `Future {
   DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
     val query = SQL("select * from bar")
     query()
   }
  }`

  Should be done as,

  `import scala.concurrent.blocking
     Future {
       blocking {
           DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
           val query = SQL("select * from bar")
           query()
       }
     }`
- This `blocking` notifies the thread pool that this task is blocking. This allows the pool to temporarily spawn new workers as needed. This is done to prevent starvation in blocking applications.
- The thread pool(by default the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global` pool) knows when the code in a  `blocking` is completed.(Since it's a fork join thread pool)
- Therefore it will remove the spare worker threads as they completes, and the pool will shrink back down to its expected size with time(Number of cores by default).
- But this scenario can also backfire if there is not enough memory to expand the thread pool.
- So for your scenario, you can use

  ```
  images.foreach(i => {

    import scala.concurrent.blocking
     Future {
      blocking {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        val query = SQL("insert into .........")
        query()
      }
    }
  })
  ```
- If you're doing a lot of blocking I/O, then it's a good practice to create a separate thread-pool/execution context and execute all blocking calls in that pool.

References :

- [scala-best-practices](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md)
- [demystifying-the-blocking-construct-in-scala-futures](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-the-blocking-construct-in-scala-futures)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that `blocking` is but a recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068064/scala-concurrent-blocking-what-does-it-actually-do and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681389/use-case-of-scala-concurrent-blocking